# When to send a thank you for the interview?

Tags: professionalism, follow-up

I am in the initial stages of being considered for a position at a different company, where I was encouraged to apply by a friend (Who would also be my supervisor in the new position).

The first part was a semi informal sit down with him and two other people that were evaluating my knowledge base and how well I would get along with them. I had that yesterday, but one of the people was unable to attend, so there will be a followup with at least that person and future supervisor.

I normally send a thank you email for interviews, but not sure if I should send it now, or wait until I have the second interview. Do I send one now, and another one after the next session, or just wait until I've met all the players and send it then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should you send multiple thank you notes for multiple interviews?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/90945/should-you-send-multiple-thank-you-notes-for-multiple-interviews)

Comment: @DavidK I think that this is the same as Crossedtheriverstyx pointed out; this question is about *when* to send it, not if you *should*.

Comment: @DarkCygnus I can't tell because the comment is deleted, but we have a lot of questions about thank you notes. The most popular one is "[Should a thank you letter be sent after an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19196/should-a-thank-you-letter-be-sent-after-an-interview)", which I agree is different than this one. I think the question I linked is the same, because thought the words used are *When* versus *Should*, the context in both is really about multiple interviews and whether a thank you should be sent after each stage or wait until after the final stage.

Comment: See also: [How many thank you letters during interview process?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/8638/how-many-thank-you-letters-during-interview-process)

Comment: @DavidK - I saw that question, and I would assume that the interviews there are either completely different panels or the same group. I wasn't sure if that covered an interview that had to be split because some members were unavailable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Send the thank you immediately to all who attended.  If someone is in the future interview who already received a thank-you note from you, it can only be to your benefit.